# Only HTTPS enabled in IIS for WCF Service but BasicHttpBinding configured with security disabled

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis-7

Bindings for a WCF Service in IIS has been configured to use HTTPS only. The endpoint declaration in web.config is using BasicHttpBinding. The binding configuration has security disabled (Security = None). Would the Service be accessible over HTTPS?

It seems to be working from client using BasicHttpBinding with Security Mode set to Transport. I was thinking this configuration will throw error but the service is being accessed correctly? Is IIS overridding the security mode configuration in this case ?